# Firebase denies permission even though auth was successful

Tags: firebase, permissions, firebase-authentication

Using `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` successfully, I still don't get permission to access the database.

This is supposed to be a backend script to generate PDFs from database data. A different script + website is used to genereate the data and works just fine.
I have crossreferenced it with that code and it won't work. Tried removing promises, won't work. Tried expanding on promises and catching them, won't work.

```
// simplified, successful auth with predefined, working email and password
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);


// this bit causes the error messages
db.collection('redacted').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log('success');
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

I expected to get a nice 'Successful' in the console, instead i get:

```
(node:4892) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
Error getting documents { FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (.\firebaseTest\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:353:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (.\firebaseTest\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:5772:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (.\firebaseTest\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:6269:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (.\firebaseTest\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:14819:43)
    at .\firebaseTest\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:14748:30
    at .\firebaseTest\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:14788:28
    at .\firebaseTest\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:7541:20
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: 'permission-denied',
  name: 'FirebaseError',
  toString: [Function] }
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your rules for firestore?

Comment: allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `db.collection('')` after you get loggend in

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
.. your code goes here.
  } 
}
```

find more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Comment: Did that, now it prints the error once, and success twice. Any idea why?

Comment: ah true, true. It's because of the async nature of the auth process. You send signIn, but it doesn't immediately logs you in, it takes some time. So it's best to check for Auth.user != null, or as Oleg said, go for the state change. That function always gets called twice, once when defined, and once when the user is logged in

Answer (score 0):

Check your rules on the Firebase console, maybe your user doesn't have permission to access the requested path.

Comment: The rules are fine for the other script, allow: ... if: require.auth,uid != null;
So it basically should grant access to any valid user, right?